# OpenGL circle rotation

Tags: c#, opengl

I'm using following code to draw my circles:

```
double theta = 2 * 3.1415926 / num_segments; 
double c = Math.Cos(theta);//precalculate the sine and cosine
double s = Math.Sin(theta);
double t;
double x = r;//we start at angle = 0 
double y = 0;

GL.glBegin(GL.GL_LINE_LOOP); 
for(int ii = 0; ii < num_segments; ii++) 
{
    float first = (float)(x * scaleX + cx) / xyFactor;
    float second = (float)(y * scaleY + cy) / xyFactor;

    GL.glVertex2f(first, second); // output Vertex 

    //apply the rotation matrix
t = x;
x = c * x - s * y;
y = s * t + c * y;
} 
GL.glEnd();
```

The problem is that when scaleX is different from scaleY then circles are transformed in the right way except for the rotation.
In my code sequence looks like this:

```
circle.Scale(tmp_p.scaleX, tmp_p.scaleY);
circle.Rotate(tmp_p.rotateAngle);
```

My question is what other calculations should i perform for circle to rotate properly when scaleX and scaleY are not equal?

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/c0cfc89146.gif](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/c0cfc89146.gif)

The circle is streched as red line shows when acctually i want it to be streched by green line.

Rotate function:

```
double cosFi = Math.Cos(angle*Math.PI/180.0);
double sinFi = Math.Sin(angle * Math.PI / 180.0);
double x, y;
double newX = 0, newY = 0;
DVector center = objectSize.CenterPoint;
y = ((MCircleCmd)cmdList[i]).m_Y;
x = ((MCircleCmd)cmdList[i]).m_X;
newX = (x - center.shiftX) * cosFi - (y - center.shiftY) * sinFi + center.shiftX;
newY = (x - center.shiftX) * sinFi + (y - center.shiftY) * cosFi + center.shiftY;
((MCircleCmd)cmdList[i]).m_X = newX;
((MCircleCmd)cmdList[i]).m_Y = newY;
UpdateSize(ref firstMove, newX, newY);
```

Scale function:

```
public void Scale(double scale) // scale > 1 - increase; scale < 1 decrease
{
    if (!isPrepared) return;
    objectSize.x1 *= scale;
    objectSize.x2 *= scale;
    objectSize.y1 *= scale;
    objectSize.y2 *= scale;
    ((MCircleCmd)cmdList[i]).m_X *= scale;
    ((MCircleCmd)cmdList[i]).m_Y *= scale;
    ((MCircleCmd)cmdList[i]).m_R *= scale;
    ((MCircleCmd)cmdList[i]).scaleX = scale;
    ((MCircleCmd)cmdList[i]).scaleY = scale;
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown us the Scale and Rotate functions. I guess the Scale function sets scaleX/Y but what does Rotate do?

Comment: The question is not clear to me. "circles are transformed in the right way except for the rotation" you say. What is it that is wrong? A drawing of the problem would be useful.

Comment: Can you post a image of the problem?

Comment: I've added additional information to help understand problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are approaching this the wrong way - you're not taking full use of the GPU if one is present. Personally, I'd approach it like this:

```
class Ellipse
{
public:
   Ellipse ()
   {
     // build an array of precalculated vertices for a unit circle
     // optionally, create a display list
   }

   void Draw ()
   {
      glBegin (...);
      // create and push a translation, rotation matrix from the m_* value
      // setup all vertices from array (or use display list)
      // pop matrix
      glEnd ();
   }

   // setters to define position, rotation and scale

 private:
    float m_rotation, m_scale_x, m_scale_y, m_x, m_y;
    glVertex2f m_vertices [...];
 };
```

This puts the job of translating and scaling into the rendering pipeline (the matrix push) and lets the hardware do the hard work.